# regexEXR V2.1 character set mismatch

Tags: regex

I was working on regex and studying the applications of character sets.

I tried the regex `/[64-bit]/g`, but the highlighted answer was contradictory; it highlighted uppercase letters, numbers and certain operators.

Why is that?

Comment: Is there any unescaped-hyphen duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you're not using the right construct. Once you fix that, everything falls into place.

It doesn't make sense to use a character class if you want to match `64-bit` literally. You should just use `/64-bit/g` as your regex in this case.

Character classes (specified by `[]`) have different rules than the rest of the regex. They match a single character listed within (or not listed, if it's a negated char class).

A range of characters can also be specified to match, and that is where you have your problem. According to any [online ASCII chart](http://www.ascii-code.com/), `4` is #52 in the table, and `b` is #98. (Note that `[4-bit]` is actually an equivalent regex.) Between those two points, there are many characters, including the uppercase letters. That is why you are getting unexpected matches.